# Concatenate data and print at the end of crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a main report and a sub report in crystal reports. Main report consists of only 2 pages and I kept the sub report in the footer of main report. The sub report retrieves data from the data base and then should display it. I have divided the text and stored in the database. I will have to retrieve all the text, concatenate it and then display it. I created a field(Say X) and then concatenated all of the data and kept X in the footer. But it is not displaying it as I want it because the data is aligned to the bottom of the page(obviously).
I want to display the data right after the Page header. There can be upto 200 records in the table. So the report should print the field X only after the 200 records are read and are concatenated to the field X. One method I could think of is...retrieve the number of records in the table and in the var X, declare a static field and take the count. Once the count is equal to the number of records in table, print field X else suppress it all the times.

I am very new to crystal reports, please can anyone help me with the code?

Comment: Place in page footer

Comment: No, it will be aligned to the bottom...isn't it?

Comment: You need at the bottom of page or at end of report